# How to use an find best match based on the wording within the same cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on
[Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMxfhzsN_eAO5kZZcBv4Difq2ybVU29mh8s__8a5gSk/edit?usp=sharing), In this I need find the best match based on the word in this sheet.

Our most of the basic Look up function like Vlookup, Hlookup, Xlookup or Index-match only support for Look the whole wording.

Then I used [Split function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to {"=SPLIT(E3," ")"}, Split all word in 2nd Table.

Then I wrote [formula](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)  Using LET, HSTACK, BYROW, TOROW , CHOOSEROWS and Other formula.
Below is the formula

=LET(a,HSTACK($D$2:$D$5, BYROW(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(XMATCH($F$2:$H$5,SPLIT(A2," "))),0),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))),TOROW(CHOOSEROWS(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(a,INDEX(a,,2)<>0),2,1),,1),1)))

But I think I need to do some correction on this, because this not give the 100% accuracy.

Comment: What's the *specific* problem you're having when trying to set this up?  What have you already tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve following result with help of "Filter , IsNumber & Search Function" .[image]

Comment: Please share the formula

Comment: @indikaprasanna formula available inside the formula bar in attached picture.